# TypeScript Error (TS2345) argument of type Person | undefined is not assignable to paramater of type Person

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to typescript and not sure what i'm doing wrong here

```
interface Person{
  id:number;
  name:string
}

 export async function getPersonInfo(person: Person): Promise<Person>{
 //some code here
 return response.data.person
 }

const someFunc = () => {
const [person, setPerson] = useState<Person>();

  useEffect(() => {
     getPersonInfo(person).then((data) => {
     setPerson(data);
     });
  }, [person]);
```

passing the instance of interface with null or undefined values in **getPersonInfo** seems to be the problem. But it works if i pass an array of interface Person using useState as below

```
export async function getPersonInfo(person: Person[]): Promise<Person[]>{
//some code here
return response.data.person
}

const [persom, setPerson] = useState<Person[]>([])

useEffect(() => {
getPersonInfo(person: Person[]).then((data) => {
setPerson(data);
});
```

**why does it work for an array but not for a single object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the call of `useState()`. Since you don't pass the initial value, the variable `person` will be undefined at first. In your second code, you pass an empty array to the function so that the variable will be an empty array which matches the type `Person[]`.

To solve the problem, you need to do either initialize the state with the Person object or accept `undefined` as the argument of the function.

```
export async function getPersonInfo(person?: Person): Promise<Person>{
  //some code here
  return response.data.person
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is with

```js
const [person, setPerson] = useState<Person>();
vs
const [persom, setPerson] = useState<Person[]>([])
```

In your first one (where it's erroring), the initial value of `person` is undefined so the compiler understands this to mean that `person` can be a `Person` or undefined. In your second one, you're initializing `person` as an empty array so the compiler understands this to mean it's an array of `Person`, but there's just no `Person` objects in it.

And the real problem ends up surfacing here:

```
export async function getPersonInfo(person: Person): Promise<Person>{
   //some code here
   return response.data.person
}
```

because `getPersonInfo` takes in a Person. So you either need to first make sure there's a person, or (not likely ideal) have `getPersonInfo` take in a `Person | undefined`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (person) {
    getPersonInfo(person).then((data) => {
      setPerson(data);
    });
  }
}, [person]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your initial value for person is undefined.

So person is undefined until you receive the person from the api call and set it.

As an array you are setting the initial value to an empty array - it is an array, just empty. But it’s not undefined. So Person[] is a valid type.